# Encoding error when saving excel file to Django FielField

Tags: python, django, excel, django-models

Have a good day, everyone.

While building a django app I have come to a problem I hope I can get help with.

I'm generating manually an excel file using an empty pandas dataframe where the headers are the contents of another model field, this file will serve as a template for the user to import data.

The file is generated sucessfully but when I try to save it to a model (so I dont have to create again the same file in the future) it gives me the folowwing error:

> 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 54: character maps to < undefined>

I'm currently using Django 2.0.3, windows 10 and my system language is Spanish (latin america)

**Here is the view**

The view receives the values 'periodo' (period) and  'programa' ('program') from a form

```
def generar_archivo_importacion(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    periodo_plantilla = Periodo.objects.get(id=request.GET['periodo'])
    programa_plantilla = Programa.objects.get(id=request.GET['programa'])

    # HERE I TRY TO GET THE DATA FOR THE DATAFRAME HEADERS
    try:
        modulos_generales = ModulosGeneralesPeriodo.objects.get(periodo__id=periodo_plantilla.id). \
            modulos_generales.all()
    except ModulosGeneralesPeriodo.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse('Error: No hay Módulos generales inscritos en este periodo, corrija este error')


    datos = {
        'Numero Documento': [],
        'Tipo Documento': [],
        'Nombre': [],
        'Apellido': [],
    }
    for modulo in modulos_generales:
        datos[modulo.nombre_modulo_normalizado] = []

    # DATAFRAME CREATION
    df = pd.DataFrame(datos)

    # FILE CREATION, nombre_archivo = name_file in spanish

    nombre_archivo = 'Plantilla puntajes 1.xlsx'
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('media/temp/' + nombre_archivo, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Puntaje')
    writer.save()

    # At this point the file is saved in 'media/temp/'

    f = open('media/temp/' + nombre_archivo, mode='r')

    # Here I create a new model object
    nueva_plantilla = PlantillasPuntaje(programa=programa_plantilla, periodo=periodo_plantilla)

    # This is where I suposse the problem is, when I try to save the file I just created
    nueva_plantilla.archivo.save(nombre_archivo, File(open('media/temp/'+ nombre_archivo)))

# Im returning a string at the moment
return HttpResponse('it works')
```

**Here is the Model**

```
class PlantillasPuntaje(models.Model):
    programa = models.ForeignKey(Programa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    periodo = models.ForeignKey(Periodo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # THE FILEFIELD
    archivo = models.FileField(upload_to='puntajes/plantillas/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    valid = models.BooleanField('Is valid', default=True)
```

Edit: Full error with traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/creararchivo/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=exRnAYkpmxUOlqY2vsxboNRYiyAMdExEZQz41mvhGo0dlrYrlyR2aW6YX6C7eL8P&archivo=puntajes&programa=1&periodo=1

Django Version: 2.0.3
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:
['indicadores',
 'localflavor',
 'django_countries',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\TesisApp\app\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\TesisApp\app\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\TesisApp\app\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\TesisApp\app\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\TesisApp\app\src\saberplus\indicadores\views.py" in generar_archivo_importacion
  117.         nueva_plantilla.archivo.save(nombre_archivo, File(open('media/temp/'+ nombre_archivo)))

File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\TesisApp\app\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in save
  87.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)

File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\TesisApp\app\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in save
  49.         return self._save(name, content)

File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\TesisApp\app\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in _save
  268.                         for chunk in content.chunks():

File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\TesisApp\app\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\base.py" in chunks
  71.             data = self.read(chunk_size)

File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\TesisApp\app\lib\encodings\cp1252.py" in decode
  23.         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /creararchivo/
Exception Value: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 54: character maps to <undefined>
```

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Can you post the *entire* error message with traceback? My is hunch this error is occurring in the excel writer, not django.

Comment: I'll add it inmediatly

Comment: You should open the file with the proper encoding. If you don't supply it, it will default to the system encoding, which appears to be `cp1252`. You probably want to open it with utf-8 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying a mode of binary `'rb'` when you open the Excel file for reading.

```
nueva_plantilla.archivo.save(nombre_archivo, File(open('media/temp/'+ nombre_archivo, 'rb')))
```

Comment: Try explicitly specifying the encoding `open('media/temp/'+ nombre_archivo, mode='rb', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: I have to apologize, the first solution proposed actually worked.
I separated the code 3 lines above the one you proposed to changue and forgot to apply that:

"f = open('media/temp/' + nombre_archivo, mode='rb') // 
nueva_plantilla.archivo.save(nombre_archivo, File(open('media/temp/'+ nombre_archivo, 'r')))"

I´m marking this as an answer.

Comment: Normally, when you open a file, python tries to encode it to text by default. When you open a file in binary mode, Python will not try to encode the data into text, therefore you won't run into the encoding error.